# Is there a way to prove this sequence converges uniformly on $x\in [0,1]$ (related to an integral)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I want to learn if there's a way to determine if the following sequence converges uniformly on $x\in [0,1]$

$$a_{n+1}(x)=e^{-xa_{n}(x)},\quad a_{0}(x)=1$$

By mathematical induction, I can show that if $0\leq a_{1}(x)\leq 1$ when $0\leq x\leq 1$, then

$$0\leq a_{n+1}(x)\leq 1$$

holds $\forall\, n\in\mathbb{N}$ on that interval. I think my next step would be to prove that

$$\big|a_{n+2}(x)-a_{n+1}(x)\big|\leq \big|a_{n+1}(x)-a_{n}(x)\big|$$

but I'm not sure how to do that. Perhaps viz. a 2nd order expansion of $e^{-x}$ ? (I really don't know what I'm doing when it comes to convergence so I apologize if my work isn't anywhere close). If context helps at all, the reason why I'm asking is because I wanted to evaluate the following integral:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}a_{n}(x)\mathrm dx \stackrel{?}{=}\frac{1}{2}\Omega^{2}+\Omega$$
whereby $a_{n}(x)$ is the aformentioned sequence, and $\Omega$ represents the [Omega constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant). Numerical approximations hint that the solution is fairly close (possibly correct) but I can't be certain. Consider expanding the domain of integration beyond $[0,1]$...

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{q\ln q}a_{n}(x)\mathrm dx \stackrel{?}{=}\frac{1}{2}\ln^{2}q\, + \ln q,\quad q\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}$$

Numerical approximations are still close, but further off...perhaps because my skills at numerical approximations are bad, or because $a_{n}(x)$ doesn't converge uniformly on larger domains. It seems like for

$$g(q) = \Bigg|\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{q\ln q}a_{n}(x)\mathrm dx - \Bigg(\frac{1}{2}\ln^{2}q\, + \ln q\Bigg)\Bigg|$$

that $g(q)$ cycles and the magnitude gets increasingly larger as $q\to\infty$.

Is there a way to determine a cut-off in the domain $[0,\infty)$ where the sequence $a_{n}(x)$ doesn't converge anymore? Or is that not how it works (again I apologize if my questions come off uninformed)

Comment: As a sanity check: *if* the sequence of functions converges, then the pointwise limit is $a\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $a(x) = e^{-x a(x)}$, whose solutions are going to give you $W$, and the integral $\int_0^1 W(x)/x dx$ is exactly what you conjecture.